# Get JSON key from object - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON object that contains a map of values. The keys of these map item are predefined. I use `ng-repeat` to create a button for each map item and I pass the item to the method via `ng-click`.

To execute a certain call, I now need the key of the item. How can I get the key of the given item?

**The JSON looks like**

```
"map": {
    "0": {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "123",
    },
    "1": {
      "id": 5,
      "value": "567",
    }
}
```

**.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in object.map">
    <button ng-click="load(item)" type="button">A</button>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.load= function(item) {
    // HOW TO GET THE KEY OF THE GIVEN MAP ITEM
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the properties of this object, getting the pair `(key, item)`, using the following syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in object.map">
    <button ng-click="load(key, item)" type="button">A</button>
</div>
```

In this way, you pass the `key` of the item to the `load` function. In this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties), you can find more details about this syntax for `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in object.map">
    <button ng-click="load(key,value)" type="button">A</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can use is getting object into your controller and acess keys there using Object.keys(objname).

app.js will look sommething like this:

```
$scope.load= function(item) {
  let key = Object.keys(item);
};
```